# Ubuntu server UFW log files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging, ufw

I got a server running Ubuntu 18.04. I have set up `ufw` with the basic deny all incoming, allow all outgoing with a few specific ports being allowed in. With logging activated on level low I still can't find any log files containing ufw-entries.
I got no `/var/log/ufw*` files, no entries in `/var/log/syslog`, none in `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/kern.log`.

`/etc/rsyslog.d/20-ufw.conf` says:

```
# Log kernel generated UFW log messages to file
:msg,contains,"[UFW " /var/log/ufw.log

# Uncomment the following to stop logging anything that matches the last rule.
# Doing this will stop logging kernel generated UFW log messages to the file
# normally containing kern.* messages (eg, /var/log/kern.log)
#& stop
```

`rsyslog` is running and the only way I can see messages beeing created is `sudo dmesg | grep '\[UFW'`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you try to increase log level for ufw?
by default it has "low" level
you might consider to increase your log level, or check external firewall in case of hosting machine on cloud provider platform, in last case you need to edit firewall rules there too.

Comment: No, I didn't try that yet. There is no other firewall in place I know about. As I can see the blocked requests using `dmesg` if I for example try to connect to the blocked default ssh-port, I don't see how the level should help that being written to syslog or ufw.log.

Comment: please look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42388079/10674026 that solved it for me